# Nest js Ur redirect not working using @Redirect() with status code 307 and 302

Tags: nestjs

I am currently working on a Nest.js application and encountering an issue with redirecting URLs to a new destination. Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
@Get('/test')
    @Redirect('/newtest',307)   
    public async redirectTest(){

    }

    @Get('/newtest')
    public async getMyTest(): Promise<
        TestDto[]
    > {
        
       // service calls
        return testData
    }
```

It will throw 404 error for '/newtest'.When iam induvadully call the '/newtest 'its working fine. can some one face the similar issue